# activity fragment addToBackStack()

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Такая ситуация. Есть последовательность. В активность добавляем первый фрагмент. Затем замещаем его вторым фрагментом. Как вернуться кнопкой "Back" из второго фрагмента сразу в активность?

Пытался колдовать с addToBackStack(), ничего не получилось. С onBackPressed() тоже пытался колдовать, тоже ничего не получилось. И с тем и с тем вместе пробовал, тоже ноль результата. Спасите помогите!

Comment: не понятно, что вы хотите. Фрагменты добавляются в активность, поэтому вернуться из второго фрагмента в активность не получится - вы и так там)

Comment: При нажатии back нужно вернуться в активность без фрагментов. А у меня возвращается активность с первым фрагментом.

Comment: То есть нужно убрать все фрагменты из активности, нажатием back.

Comment: добавьте в `onBackPressed` `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();` сколько нужно раз. Можно с try/catch блоком, чтобы NPE не поймать